# Restricting browsing images and other folders in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to restrict user from browsing the image or other folders with URL address without login or been authorized ?

For Example : http://xyx.com/Images/image.png should not be allowed and the image should not be displayed.

I am using MVC 4 . Please do provide me the approach and the mechanism to stop access.

Answer (score 2):

You should do this with `web.config`. Place a config file in the `images` folder with content something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
          <deny users ="?" /> <!--Deny all users who are anonymous (not logged in) -->
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

To use the main `web.config` file for your application, see the following:

```
<location path="Images">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users ="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Can the same web configuration we can use in MVC 4 ???

Comment: It does not work in MVC 4 Web config. The user is able to browse the image file via direct URL path http://xyz.com/Images/Image.png

Comment: @user2819626 Why can't you just add the other config file in your images folder? Both ways work fine for me. Also make sure that the second snippet is inside the `configuration` section of your main `web.config`.

Answer (score 1):

For restricting folder configure the below given configuration block in your `Web.config`

```
<configuration>
<location path="ImageDirectory">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="*"/> <!-- Denies all users -->
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
</configuration>
```

As per the above configuration Anonymous users can not access `ImageDirectory` folder and its contents.

Comment: It works in asp.net without MVC.

Comment: The same approach you can use in MVC also..

Answer (score -2):

You need to use

İf

Else

Nothing more.

Also please check below

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/12/23/asp-net-mvc-using-profilerequiredattribute-to-restrict-access-to-pages.aspx